# Equivalent of (assert (= a 10)) in Z3Py

Tags: z3, z3py

I am creating a tree with some nodes. Each node has certain properties associated with it like cost. The idea is to find the path with the lowest cost. Leaf nodes have cost already declared for them. The cost for non-leaf nodes will be defined based on their child with the cheapest cost.
I am trying to write the assertion for defining the costs of leaf nodes.

I have the working code in SMT-LIB 2.0 Standard. I have looked at python-based examples available for Z3, but couldn't find a solution.

Note: I am very new to SMT Solvers such as Z3.

I know we can simply write `(assert (= a 10))` using SMT-LIB 2.0 standard. For Python, I have tried `a = IntVal("10")`. I am not sure if it is what I need.

I want to write `(assert (= a 10))` similar code using Z3Py. Any kind of assistance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In z3py, this would simply be:

```py
from z3 import *

s = Solver()

a = Int('a')

s.add(a == 10)

print s.check()
print s.model()
```

which prints:

```
sat
[a = 10]
```

### Assignment vs Equality

When you're programming in SMTLib or Z3py, it's best to think of equality as a comparison, not an assignment. When you say:

```
(assert (= a 10))
```

in SMTLib, you are *not* assigning anything to `a`. All you are saying is that the value of `a` should compare equal to `10`. In fact, the expression `(= a 10)` has type `Bool`, so you can equivalently say:

```
(assert (= true (= a 10)))
```

which would be redundant, but it illustrates the point.

The confusion is, of course, "equality comparison" in SMTLib is called `=`, but in Python it is `==`; and worse, `=` is meaningful in Python as assignment; but it doesn't mean what you're trying to say. If you're familiar with functional programming, think of SMTLib/Z3Py programs as a collection of variables of differing types and assertions about relationships between them.

Hope that helps! Asking concrete questions is always better than English prose; feel free to post code segments that might be confusing.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was trying to do s.add(a=10) which gave me an error. Could you help me understand why it has to be == rather than = (assignment operator)?

Comment: See my updated answer. Long story short: It's best to think equality in SMTLib and Z3py in terms of assertions and comparisons, instead of assignment as found in imperative languages.